# chrome app - chrome.desktopCapture not working when using webview

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webview, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to get screensharing working from inside a webview in a chrome packaged app.

I currently have a webpage that calls window.postMessage when desktop sharing is required and I need chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia to send back the chromeMediaSourceId to allow navigator.webkitGetUserMedia to be called.

My chrome app main html page just has a `<webview>` tag pointing to the external website.

I have been able to grab the message from the webview and send it to background.js and call

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, callback) {

   chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(['screen'],sender.tab, function (streamid) {
                message.type = 'gotScreen';
                message.streamId = streamid;
                callback(message);
            });
});
```

I get the screen selector popup and after selecting a screen the streamId is sent via the callback which posts a message to the webview which then calls navigator.webkitGetUserMedia with the stream id. This call fails and I get an `InvalidStateError`.

If I run the app without a webview, screen sharing works perfectly. It seems because `sender.tab` is not set that the webview doesn't have permission to use the streamId generated.

Is there a way to get screen sharing to work if you are calling navigator.webkitGetUserMedia from inside a webview and calling chrome.desktopCapture from the background.js ?

Comment: You may need handle the stream inside the app.

Comment: If I handle the stream in the app how do I go about sending it to the other client. I need to be able to stream the screen to another browser. I was hoping there would be a less convoluted way of doing this but I think without "tabs" permission enabled in packaged apps the chooseDesktopMedia call won't work from a webview.

Comment: @DaveW did you ever get this to work? if so, how?
Also, how will the "tabs" permissions make this work?

Comment: Nope sorry, we ended up giving up on it.